# Is there a UIView resize event?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have a view that has rows and columns of imageviews in it.

If this view is resized, I need to rearrange the imageviews positions.

This view is a subview of another view that gets resized.

Is there a way to detect when this view is being resized?

Comment: When is the view resized? When the device rotates, or when the user rotates it using multi-touch?

Comment: This view is resized when the user taps on a button on another view (master view).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

As Uli commented below, the proper way to do it is override `layoutSubviews` and layout the imageViews there.

If, for some reason, you can't subclass and override `layoutSubviews`, observing `bounds` should work, even when being kind of dirty. Even worse, there is a risk with observing - Apple does not guarantee KVO works on UIKit classes. Read the discussion with Apple engineer here: [When does an associated object get released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039309/when-does-an-associated-object-get-released)

**original answer:**

You can use key-value observing:

```
[yourView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:0 context:nil];
```

and implement:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == yourView && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"bounds"]) {
        // do your stuff, or better schedule to run later using performSelector:withObject:afterDuration:
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, laying out subviews is exactly what layoutSubviews is for, so observing size changes, while functional, is IMO bad design.

Comment: @uliwitness well they do keep changing this stuff. Anyway, now you should use `viewWillTransition` etc. etc.

Comment: viewWillTransition of for UIViewControllers, not UIView.

Comment: Is using `layoutSubviews` still a recommended method if, depending on the current size of the view, different subviews needed to be added/removed and different constraints need to be added/removed?

Comment: Well, I think I just answered this for my case. When I do the setup (dependent on size) I need in an override of bounds, it works. When I do it in layoutSubviews it doesn't.

Answer (score 105):

In a `UIView` subclass, *property observers* can be used:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Without subclassing, *key-value observation* with *smart key-paths* will do:

```
var boundsObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

func beginObservingBounds() {
    boundsObservation = observe(\.bounds) { capturedSelf, _ in
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ali Why do you think so?

Comment: on load frame changes but it looks like bounds does not (I know it is strange and maybe I am dong something wrong )

Comment: @Ali: as it has been mentioned a couple of times here: `frame` is a derived and runtime calculated property. do not override this, unless you have a very smart and knowing reason to do so. otherwise: use `bounds` or (even better) `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` gets called multiple times. If you want to set layout constraints with more precise calculation, then `layoutSubviews` won't work.

Comment: Such a great way to create a circle. Thanks! `override var bounds: CGRect { didSet { layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width / 2 }}`

Comment: Detecting `bounds` or `frame` change is not guaranteed to work, depending on where you put your view in the view hierarchy. I'd override `layoutSubviews` instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901862/1452174) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003296/1452174) answers.

Comment: Apple REALLY need to fix this API. It's broken, IMO. We need a property or callback that will tell us just once when our view is ready for customisation, with a fully populated frame/bounds.

Answer (score 34):

Create subclass of UIView, and override layoutSubviews

Comment: the trouble with this is that subviews can not only change their size, but they can animate that size change. When UIView runs the animation, it does not call layoutSubviews each time.

Comment: @DavidJeske UIViewAnimationOptions  has an option called UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews. I think this maybe help. : )

Answer (score 10):

Swift 4 keypath KVO -- This is how I detect autorotate and moving to iPad side panel. Should work work any view. Had to observe the UIView's layer.

```
private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    observer = view.layer.observe(\.bounds) { object, _ in
        print(object.bounds)
    }
    // ...
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    observer?.invalidate()
    //...
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I'm new to Swift and I'm unsure on the \.bounds syntax you used here. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: here is more discussion: https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4/blob/master/Whats-new-in-Swift-4.playground/Pages/Key%20paths.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

Comment: `.layer` did the trick! Do you know why using `view.observe` doesn't work?

Comment: @d4Rk - I don't know. My guess is that layer bounds less ambiguous than UIView frames. For example, UITableView's contentOffset will affect the final coordinates of its subViews. Not sure.

Comment: THIS IS A GREAT ANSWER FOR ME. My case is that I'm using AutoLayout for laying out my views. BUT UICollectionViewFlowLayout forces you to give an explicit itemSize. but when your collectionView size changes (like in my case when I'm showing a toolbar with AutoLayout) - the itemSize remains the same and throws =[ the observer is the cleanest approach I got so far. and the best one!!

Answer (score 8):

Pretty old but still a good question. In Apple's sample code, and in some of their private UIView subclasses, they override setBounds roughly like:

```
-(void)setBounds:(CGRect)newBounds {
    BOOL const isResize = !CGSizeEqualToSize(newBounds.size, self.bounds.size);
    if (isResize) [self prepareToResizeTo:newBounds.size]; // probably saves 
    [super setBounds:newBounds];
    if (isResize) [self recoverFromResizing];
}
```

Overriding `setFrame:` is NOT a good idea. `frame` is derived from `center`, `bounds`, and `transform`, so iOS will not necessarily call `setFrame:`.

Comment: This is true (in theory). However, `setBounds:` is not called either when setting the frame property (at least on iOS 7.1). This could be an optimization Apple added to avoid the additional message.

Comment: … and bad design on Apple's side not to call their own accessors.

Comment: In fact, _both_ `frame` and `bounds` are derived from the view's underlying `CALayer`; they just call through to the layer's getter. And `setFrame:` sets the layer's frame, while `setBounds:` sets the layer bounds. So you cannot just override one or the other. Also, `layoutSubviews` gets called excessively (not just on geometry changes), so it may not always be a good option either. Still looking...

Answer (score 7):

You can create a subclass of UIView and override the

setFrame:(CGRect)frame

method.  This is the method called when the frame (i.e. the size) of the view is changed.  Do something like this:

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  // Call the parent class to move the view
  [super setFrame:frame];

  // Do your custom code here.
}
```

Comment: Sensible and functional. Good call.

Comment: FYI This does not work for UIImageView subclass. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216684/uiimageview-subclass-needs-to-handle-resize

Comment: Also, `setFrame:` wasn't called on my `UITextView` subclass during resizing caused by autorotation whereas `layoutSubviews:` was. Note: I'm using auto layout & iOS 7.0.

Comment: never override `setFrame:`. `frame` is a derived property. See my answer

Answer (score -2):

If you're in a UIViewController instance, overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does the trick.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // update subviews
}
```

Comment: UIView size changed needed, not UIViewController.

Comment: @GastónAntonioMontes thanks for that! You might have noticed a relationship between `UIView` instances and `UIViewController` instances. So if you have a `UIView` instance with no VC attached, the other answers are great, but if you happen to be attached to a VC, this is your man. Sorry it's not applicable to your case.