# UITextField - max character length with emoji

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Currently I'm using this approach

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
     NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
     if(newLength <= 25) {
         self.charsLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 25 - newLength];
     }
     return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;
}
```

where `charsLeft` is label showed in user interface.

Problem came out with `emoji`. If user enter `emoji` symbol and then delete it, `newLength` is going to be equal to 1. So user will see that he have only 24 chars left.

I do know that emoji symbols is surrogate pairs, but I don't understand why if you deleting it than `range.length` in

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

will be equals 1 and not 2.

How I could fix wrong number in user interface? 
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this problem, I found below two solutions to fix this problem
try

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    numberWordLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/25",textView.text.length];
}
```

or

use the NSNotificationCenter (from [Does Key Value Observing Work on UITextView's Text Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333600/does-key-value-observing-work-on-uitextviews-text-property))

```
- (id)init
{
    [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(textDidChange:) 
                   name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                 object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"Observation...");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Second solution is what I was looking for. `UITextFieldDelegate` don't have `didChange` method so first fix is not suitable for me. I still thinking that this problem is bug in SDK =)