# how to use kvo to observer textfiled's text change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

the demo is very simple

```
// add a textField to viewController's view 
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 375, 40)];

self.textField = textField;

textField.placeholder = @"Please input text";

// add observer for textField's attribute "text"
[textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

and then implement the method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {


NSLog(@"----  text changed"); 
}
```

at the dealloc method :

```
- (void)dealloc {

[_textField removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text"];
}
```

but when i input text , the method  observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: do not execute

i don't know why

Comment: UIKit isn't KVO compliant in general.

Comment: thank you  , i know other method :  notification and addTarget .  that answer  maybe say : some of UIKit do not support kvo ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a target to self for the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event to the `UITextView`. See the example below:

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: thank you , i just want to use kvo to implement , but UIKit isn't KVO compliant in general

Comment: @kevnliu Yeah, you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6352525/1814918

Comment: You can't addTarget:action:forControlEvents on a UITextView, its not a UIControl.  You can however add new String property to a subclassed UITextView, which you update from the UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification.  Then KVO works on that new property.

Comment: @simplatek the question is about `UITextField`, not `UITextView` but the main problem is this way even won't work properly - it doesn't catch text changes if text is changed programmatically (without of cursor in text field)