# Vertical Alignment for UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to align vertically some text in UITextView.When I added text.It shows from top..But I need to show middle from top.Is it possible to achieve this.

Comment: Look at the UIBaselineAdjustment in the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextAlignment).

Comment: when i wrote like     txt_view_head.textAlignment=UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
it shows nothing

Comment: Before Upvote this post try to solve this.Then i will agree this is waste one.Can you?

Comment: I used that one UIBaseLineAdju... but no use

Comment: The baseline adjust.. is for horizontal alignment i think.When i used it shows only horizontal alignment not vertical(from top)

Answer (score 4):

You can be able to use the `contentOffset` property of the `UITextView` class to accomplish this.

See this [Blog](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/). I hope it helps you.

Comment: I have the textview in IB.having height of 80. I was unable to proceed with the code .It is having confusion.

Comment: To clarify for anyone reading this: If you want to vertical align and you use the code from the link Maulik provides here, you have to *uncomment* the vertical align part and *comment out* the bottom align part.

Comment: UITextView (and other UIKit classes) are not guaranteed to be KVO compliant. Relying on this could cause your code to break in future iOS versions. See this post by a member of the UIKit development team: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051404/357641

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {  
   [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:  (NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];  
   [super viewDidLoad];  
}  

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {  
   UITextView *tv = object;  
   //Center vertical alignment  
   //CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;  
   //topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );  
   //tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};  

   //Bottom vertical alignment  
   CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height);  
    topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);  
    tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};  
}
```