# UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure : unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I have a custom button class:

CustomButton.h file:

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* info;
@end
```

CustomButton.m file:

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

@synthesize info;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In my main view controller:

```
CustomButton* btn = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

[btn setInfo:@"foobar"];
NSLog(@"%@", [btn info]);

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

If it's just a simple button (`[CustomButton new]`) I don't get any error. But if I choose `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UIButton setInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x753c8c0'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as `UIButton` does not provide `initWithType:` method - you can't subclass a "typed" button. You can't create an [extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) for a library class either.
The only way to "attach" something to a predefined object is to use [associated objects](http://labs.vectorform.com/2011/07/objective-c-associated-objects/):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
    
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
NSString* info = @"foobar";
objc_setAssociatedObject(btn, "info", info, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
//Later somewhere
NSString* btnInfo = (NSString*)objc_getAssociatedObject(btn, "info");
```

The "info" can be any string you like, it's just a key to retrieve that object later.
OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN means that the object would be retained and automatically released after the `btn` object's `dealloc:` would be called. You can find more details about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039309/when-does-an-associated-object-get-released).

The other way to solve your issue is to subclass the UIButton, add your info property and make it look like disclosure button by setting custom image with `setImage:forState:` method.

Generally, coupling some data with standard UI controls is a sign of a bad architecture. Maybe you'll make a little step backwards and try to find some other way to pass that string wherether you need to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The `buttonWithType:` method you are calling is from `UIButton`, not your `CustomButton` class. The return value of `buttonWithType:` is `UIButton`. Even though you assign this to a variable of type `CustomButton` it is still a `UIButton` object. Since `UIButton` doesn't have an `info` property or a `setInfo:` method, you get the error you are seeing.

Comment: So how do I create a buttonWithType AND add other proprieties/functionalities ?

Comment: That's a good question. I just answered why you were having the problem. I don't know a good solution. Overriding `UIButton` is tricky unless you can use the standard `initWithFrame:` method to create it.