# How to know a UIView is resizing to inner side or outer side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, resize

How to know that a `UIView` is resizing and the frame is increasing or decreasing (or inner side or outer side)?

For e.g. I have a `UIImageView` (and I am using a third party [library](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView) to resize an object). Its current frame is, (someX, someY, 200,50), now if I resize in a way it changes the width to 300 and in another case it changes it to 150. I should able to know that, its increased/decreased.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event

Comment: @luiyezheng, yes but I want to know whether he size is increased or decreased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it in this way,

Added a custom delegate in above library (`SPUserResizableView.h`), `- (void)userResizableViewIsResizing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView {}`

```
- (void)userResizableViewIsResizing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView {
    id contentView = userResizableView.contentView;
    if([contentView isKindOfClass:[iOTextField class]]) {
        iOTextField *textField = (iOTextField *)contentView;        
        if([self isResizingUpWithOriginalSize:textField.referenceiOProperties.originalSize currentSize:userResizableView.frame.size withiOTextField:textField]) {
            [textField increaseFont];
        } else {
            [textField decreaseFont];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) isResizingUpWithOriginalSize:(CGSize)original currentSize:(CGSize)currentSize withiOTextField:(iOTextField *)textField {
    CGFloat width = (currentSize.width - original.width);
    CGFloat height = (currentSize.height - original.height);
    if(width <= 0.0f && height <= 0.0f) {
        textField.lastWidth = width;
        textField.lastHeight = height;
        return NO;
    } else if(width > textField.lastWidth) {
        if(textField.lastWidth <= 0.0f) {
            textField.lastWidth = width;
            textField.lastHeight = height;
            return NO;
        }
        textField.lastWidth = width;
        textField.lastHeight = height;
        return YES;
    }  else if(height > textField.lastHeight) {
        if(textField.lastHeight <= 0.0f) {
            textField.lastWidth = width;
            textField.lastHeight = height;
            return NO;
        }
        textField.lastWidth = width;
        textField.lastHeight = height;
        return YES;
    } else {
        textField.lastWidth = width;
        textField.lastHeight = height;
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Make a small change in this touch event in `SPUserResizableView.m` class.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userResizableViewIsResizing:)]) {
        [self.delegate userResizableViewIsResizing:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).  For example, if your `UIImageView *imageView` then you can:

```
[imageView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];
```

You also need to implement this method in order to react to the changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)object;
    // Do what you gotta do, like save the current size in 
    // an instance variable so you can compare and see increase/decrease in size
}
```