# How to identify when size of the child view gets changed at runtime in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, runtime, contentsize

In Xamarin iOS, I have a parent UIView and allows user to load any view inside my parent view. Now I want to know from my parent view, if any of the child view's size affected by any property's value changes (For e.g., child view's font size changed at runtime).

Could anyone help me to identify the child view size changes at runtime from parent view?

Comment: Did you see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461968/xamarin-form-ios-how-to-detect-the-uiview-size-changed ?

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk, yes. I tried LayoutSubViews override method from my parent view. But it doesn't called when font size changing on the child view.

Comment: LayoutSubViews is used for  change of `frame`  not font size , As far as i know , it is no method to monitor font size change on child view from parent view..