# Drawing a rectangle with only two rounded corners using Bezier Path and Storyboarding in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have `Table View` with 5 cells as described below. The intent is to have a `topRoundedBorderCell` with a white fill and just the `TopLeft` and `TopRight` borders rounded, then have the flexibility to add as many cells as needed with the white fill and squared corners for as many options as desired, lastly the `bottomRoundedCornerCell` will have the white fill with just the `BottomLeft` and `BottomRight` corners rounded. Creating the illusion of one long white box with rounded corners that fits all of the options pertaining to one group. 
Shown below.

***Storyboard cells breakdown:***

[image]

***When I run the app:***

[image]

However, as you can see in the 2nd image, only the `TopLeft` border is rounded, the rest remain squared.

I am using the Bezier Path `roundedRect` method in 2 separate classes of type `UIView` which I assign to the respective `views` through my `Storyboard`.

***Top Rounded Borders View:***

```
class TopRectangleRoundedCornersView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width:10.0, height:10.0))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor //white fill
    }

}
```

***Bottom Rounded Borders View:***

```
class BottomRectangleRoundedCornersView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.BottomLeft, UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor //white fill
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the bounds.origin is always 0,0 and your upper left corner is the only one being rounded it makes me think maybe the size of your view isn't set until after awakeFromNib is called.  I'm not sure about that, but I'd put a breakpoint in there and see if there's truth to that.  You also need to call `super.awakeFromNib()`

Comment: If those views are being resized (auto-resized?) then you would need to recreate the path.

Comment: yes, the views are auto resized, does that mean that I should be doing this in my Table View Controller at the time the cell is gets rendered?

Comment: It would be best in an override of UIView's `layoutSubviews` in your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your path when the views are being resized. See the answers in to question [Is there a UIView resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event) for some good advice.

My favourite would be the one suggesting adding a didSet() to the `bounds` property of the views.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: class BottomRectangleRoundedCornersView: UIView {
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.BottomLeft, UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.CGPath
            self.layer.mask = mask
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor //white fill
        }
    }
}

Comment: as you suggested I moved my code to override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        // Do stuff here
    }
} instead of using awakeFromNib. Works beautifully now!

Comment: Happy to be of assistance :)