# How to observe NSView frame change?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, frame, nsview

I have a NSView from which I need to be noticed if the frame changed.

```
class CustomView: NSView {

    override var frame: NSRect {

        didSet {
            Swift.print("changed frame: \(self.frame)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I only get this "notifikation" if the superView frame is resized.

If I do something like this inside the NSView class:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:  Notification.Name(rawValue: "changeOwnSize"), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in

          let newSize = NSSize(width: self.frame.width / 2, height: self.frame.height)
          self.setFrameSize(newSize)
}
```

The `didSet` function doesn´t react at all. Although the frame size is changed. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a UIView resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event)

Comment: try `bounds`...

Comment: @sCha it´s the same with `bounds`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two steps:

1. At some point, set your view's `postsFrameChangedNotifications` property to `true`.
2. At this point, you should be able to observe the view's `frameDidChangeNotification` using `NSNotificationCenter` (if using Swift 3, it's `NSNotification.Name.NSViewFrameDidChange` or something similar).

Comment: Does that work for iOS `UIView`s? The docs only show it supported for `NSView` in Mac OS.

Comment: I don't see any reference to a notification in the docs, so I'd assume probably not. It seems intuitive that an iOS `UIView` would be much less likely to have its frame changed without your program code having been behind it.

Comment: iOS seems to rely on things like KVO and notifications a lot less than Mac OS, I think because they are rather "heavyweight" and require both more memory and more CPU horsepower. My guess is that Apple decided to drop that feature when they were implementing iOS views.

Comment: Works great. Took a while till i found out that the notified object is the whole NSView, not only NSRect. Thanks!

Comment: In XCode 11 (Swift 5), the notification name is `NSView.frameDidChangeNotification`