# Is there a UIWindow resize event for an IOS app under MacOS on Apple M1

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1, uiwindow

Running an IOS app under MacOS on an Apple M1 processor:

We are looking for a way to be notified when the app's window is resized by the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a UIView resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000664/is-there-a-uiview-resize-event)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is a full screen app and the views are not notified of the window change (presumably because there would never be a window change on a physical iPad/iPhone).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

This function gets called for every change in window size for all 'flavors' of app compilation: IOS app (under MacOS on Apple M1), Mac Catalyst, etc.